# How to balance fill int into a symmetric matrix

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a matrix `A`, it is symmetric. That is `A(i,j)=A(j,i)`

The value of `A(i,j)` can be `i` or `j`.

How can I fill the value into matrix A to make sure the exist times of each value as close as possible? (or as balance as possible)? Is there any algorithm can handle this?

### Example A:

```
A = 1 1 1 1
    1 2 2 2
    1 2 3 3
    1 2 3 4 
exist times of 1 is 7
exist times of 2 is 5
exist times of 3 is 3
exist times of 4 is 1
```

### Example B:

```
A = 1 2 1 1
    2 2 3 2
    1 3 3 4
    1 2 4 4 
exist times of 1 is 5
exist times of 2 is 4
exist times of 3 is 3
exist times of 4 is 3
```

In example B the values is (5,4,3,3), they are closer than example A (7,5,3,1)

I am looking forward a solution for nxn matrix.

### Extend

If the matrix is sparse, that is the some element can not be filled in matrix. Which algorithm can be used to handle this problem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How do you define "as close as possible"? Are you trying to do something like minimize the variance of the result?

Comment: Yes sir. But I do not need the global optimization solution if it is very hard to obtain. A simple solution is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution written in python based on Weighted Bipartite Matching (or the isomorphic Minimum Cost Flow problem.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
filename: mcf_matrix_assign.py
purpose:  demonstrate the use of weighted bipartite matching (isomorphic to MCF
          with a suitable transform) to solve a matrix assignment problem with
          certain conditions and optimization goals.
"""

import networkx as nx

N = 5
K = N # ensure K is large enough to satisfy flow, N <= K <= N*N
      # setting K larger simply means a longer runtime 

G = nx.DiGraph()
total_demand = 0

for i in range(N*N):
    # assert a row-major linear indexing of the matrix
    row, col = i / N, i % N
    if row >= col:
        continue # symmetry fix certain values
    total_demand += 1
    G.add_node('s'+str(i),demand=-1);
    G.add_edge('s'+str(i), 'v'+str(row), weight = 0, capacity = 1)
    G.add_edge('s'+str(i), 'v'+str(col), weight = 0, capacity = 1)

G.add_node('sink', demand = total_demand)

# attach each 'value' to the sink with incrementally larger weight
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(K):
        dummy_node = 'v'+str(i)+'w'+str(j)
        G.add_edge('v'+str(i), dummy_node, weight = j, capacity = 1)
        G.add_edge(dummy_node, 'sink', weight = 0, capacity = 1)

flow_dict = nx.min_cost_flow(G)

# decode the solution to get the matrix assignment reported by the MCF (or
# equivalently weighted bipartite matching)
solution = [ -1 for i in range(N*N) ]
for i in range(N*N):
    # assert a row-major linear indexing of the matrix
    row, col = i / N, i % N
    if row == col:
        solution[i] = row
        continue # symmetry fix certain values
    if row > col:
        solution[i] = solution[col*N+row]
        continue # symmetry fix certain values
    adjacency = flow_dict['s'+str(i)]
    solution[i] = row if adjacency['v'+str(row)] == 1 else col;


# print the solution
for row in range(N):
    print ''.join(['-' for _ in range(4*N+1)])
    print '|',
    for col in range(N):
        print str(solution[row*N+col]+1) + ' |',
    print '\n',
print ''.join(['-' for _ in range(4*N+1)])

print 'Histogram summary:'
counts = [ (i+1, sum([ 0 if s != i else 1 for s in solution ])) for i in range(N) ]
for value, count in counts:
    print ' Value ', value, " appears ", count, " times."
```

This produces the solution:

```
---------------------
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 | 
---------------------
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 
---------------------
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 
---------------------
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 
---------------------
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 
---------------------
Histogram summary:
 Value  1  appears  5  times.
 Value  2  appears  5  times.
 Value  3  appears  5  times.
 Value  4  appears  5  times.
 Value  5  appears  5  times.
```

And here is the solution when `N=4` in the script.

```
-----------------
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 
-----------------
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
-----------------
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 
-----------------
| 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 
-----------------
Histogram summary:
 Value  1  appears  3  times.
 Value  2  appears  3  times.
 Value  3  appears  5  times.
 Value  4  appears  5  times.
```

It's fairly easy to prove that this will always find an optimal answer in polynomial time.

### Explanation

It is probably easiest to explain what is happening by describing the graph construction for a small case. For this discussion, fix `N=3`.

In this case we have a matrix assignment with variables

```
X s0 s1
X X  s2
X X  X
```

where `X` denotes a fixed value and `sk` denotes the `k`th slot in the array to fill.

In this case we also have 3 available value assignments [1,2,3] for each of the slots `sk`. (This is where it is easy to make modifications to the "allowed" values for any `sk`.)

If we construct a bipartite graph between the slots `sk` and the value assignments `v1,v2,v3` in a way that edges of capacity 1 and weight zero are used to connect `sk` to each legal `vi` assignment, we can then solve it easily using MCF.

For illustration, the appropriate graph for `N=3` is shown below:
[image: Graph used in MCF for the N=3 case.]

Once the minimum cost flow is computed, we can decode the assignment by checking which edges are used in the solution.

### A note on performance

networkx was used here in python purely out of convenience, it is by no means efficient in any sense of the word. The quality of implementation of the MCF algorithm in networkx is quite low and I would not recommend trying to scale it up.

For serious application, I would instead recommend the lemon MCF library (in particular the cost-scaling algorithm is competitive) or, you can use Andrew Goldberg's implementation of cost-scaling (which is hard to find but exists) and is probably quite efficient as well.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, sir. I want the solution matrix is symmtric. Your solution is not symmetric.

Comment: Okay, fairly trivial changes to make it produce a symmetric solution.

Comment: Sir, could you please explain why the fill matrix problem can be converted into Weighted Bipartite Matching problem? I can not quite understand that. Thanks.

Comment: @XuHui: ok added explanation and some comments on efficiency. Note, if you just care about the original problem, the solution presented by Daniel will be best.

Comment: Thanks sir, I can understand better now. edge from source to sk determine the location at matrix need to be filled. edge from source si to vj determine the value filled at sk. the vj back to source play a role like penalty function to make sure the times of value be filled close to each other. But I still confuse that how can we ensure each edge in graph is full filled or not filled at all? For example, how can we ensure s1 to v1 is 0, s1 to v3 is 1? Or s1 to v1 is 1, s1 to v3 is 0? May be they can be 0.5 and 0.5?

Comment: That guarantee comes from total unimodularity, in this context, from MCF.  It might be helpful to understand this concept (total unimodularity) it.is perhaps the most important concept in combinatorial optimization:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity

Comment: Thanks for sharing sir. I now can fully understand. : )

Answer (score 1):

Found one solution, but without a real algorithm...

```
1 2 3 1 1
2 2 3 4 2
3 3 3 4 5
1 4 4 4 5
1 2 5 5 5
```

Basically: 25/5=5, looked for how to fill with 5 of each 1-5.
for 5 - reversed L from corner,
then up and left one spot for 4s,
and for 3s.
got "creative" for 2s and 1s...
I guess it's kind of algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

There is a special pattern to follow in order to get the best possible result. For each column (of row 1), start filling the matrix diagonally with values 1, 2, ..., n, fixing the correspondent symmetric slot. At the end, you will have the best possible result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n = 4;  //size of matrix
    
    int values[n];      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) values[i] = 0;
    int matrix[n][n];   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) matrix[i][j] = -1;
    
    for(int c = 0; c < n; c++){
        int i = 0, j = c;
        for(int x = 0; x < n; x++){
            if(matrix[i][j] != -1) {
                break;
            }
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i] = x;
            i = (i + 1) % n;
            j = (j + 1) % n;
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout<<matrix[i][j] + 1<<" ";
            values[matrix[i][j]]++;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout<<(i + 1)<<" appears "<<values[i]<<" times"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 1 1 4 
1 2 2 2 
1 2 3 3 
4 2 3 4 

1 appears 5 times
2 appears 5 times
3 appears 3 times
4 appears 3 times
```

You can test it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SJ4Uxr4yP).

The complexity is O(n²), since you have to fill all the matrix.

When `n` is odd, the solution is always `n` occurrences for each number, but when `n` is even, this is impossible.

Comment: Sir, I want 1,2,3,4,5 be filled into the matrix. A(i,j) should be i or j.

Comment: I've just updated the answer to fit what you expect. Just change `n` to test for any matrix size.

Comment: Sir, If the matrix is sparse, that is the some element can not be filled but keep zero. do you have some advice?

Comment: While this solution appears correct, once you add elements that can not be filled I doubt this pattern will generalize. 

The weighted bipartite matching solution can easily be extended to support avoid filling select elements.

Comment: All elements will be filled, there is no chance an element will be ignored. This solution is general and works for any size. Just try it for all `n` and take your conclusion.

Comment: @Daniel I don't think you understood the comment, it specifically talks about a variation on the problem where select elements *must* be ignored. I was simply stating that I doubt this solution generalizes to that case.

Comment: I don't remember seeing OP asking anything about variations of the problem except for the problem itself, which was what I tried to solve. Why should I worry about "a variation on the problem where select elements must be ignored" if OP doesn't even mention this?

Comment: The OP directly mentioned this in his comment (which I was responding to): "Sir, If the matrix is sparse, that is the some element can not be filled but keep zero. do you have some advice?" I did say that your solution appears correct for the _original_ problem but likely *not* for the _variation_ the OP directly asked about. You did not supply a proof, nor did I bother to prove the pattern you found would work, but all evidence seems to suggest it does only for the _original_ problem.

Comment: Thanks sir, your solution is elegant and concise. :) @Daniel.